# Can't access docker container by port mapping

Tags: docker

Host: Digital Ocean
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Docker version: 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe

#### example 1

`docker run -itd --name web -p 9000:80 php:7.2:apache`

```
| 76a6235c907c | php:7.2-apache | "docker-php-entrypoi…" | 5 days ago | Up 5 days | 0.0.0.0:9000->80/tcp | web   |
```

The container started successfully, but I can't access the service

- curl localhost:9000
- curl 0.0.0.0:9000
- curl 127.0.0.1:9000

I got `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`, even I turn off the firewall

but it works **INSIDE** the container

`docker exec web curl -sL localhost:80`

got

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access this resource.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

#### example 2

`docker run --rm busybox ping www.google.com`

got

`ping: bad address 'www.google.com'`

I think it's about virtual ethernet card, I installed docker via `https://get.docker.com/`, and already uninstalled entirely and re-install again, still the same

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to open ports on the digital ocean cloud firewall. Also, check the your VPS firewall too.